# CreateProcess - lpApplicationName vs lpCommandLine

Tags: c++, winapi, parameters, process

I've been using the CreateProcess Win API, and I was wondering what the difference was between using the lpApplicationName and lpCommandLine for arguments v.s. just the lpCommandLine parameter.

For example:

```
CreateProcess(NULL, L"C:\Path\To\Notepad.exe", L"C:\Path\To\File\To\Load.txt"... etc
CreateProcess(NULL, NULL, L"C:\Path\To\Notepad.exe C:\Path\To\File\To\Load.txt"... etc
```

I assume that the second option, where only lpCommandLine is used would be like opening up cmd.exe and running that exact line. But what about the first line, is it loading up the application and specifying the command line arguments differently?

I've had a look at the MSDN documentation for the API but it doesn't seem to really detail whats happening, that what that parameters can contain, which is fine, but I'm just confused about what I should be doing when there are multiple ways to do it.

Please note, I know the two sample lines may not work as lpCommandLine requires a LPTSTR, not LPCTSTR. Its just for ease of understanding.

Thanks a lot for any help!

Andy

Comment: What makes you say that MSDN isn't explaining in detail what's going on? It can hardly be more detailled. In three words, lpApplicationName more or less does exactly what you ask for and nothing more, whereas lpCommandLine adds a lot of interpretation and magic (appending extensions, searching PATH, etc). And, like John said, often the best way is to use both.

Comment: Ok, maybe there is some detail that I didn't understand / missed first time round, but it still feels a little bit ambiguous to me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The recommended way is to to use both parameters.   If you do not specify lpApplicationName you let Windows parse lpCommandLine  to figure out the application name.   Because space is a valid character in file names and directory names, this can (in rare cases) lead to wrong application being run.   (e.g. if you have c:\program.exe and you start a program under c:\program files in Windows XP).

In both cases you should use the application name in lpCommandLine since this is used to calculate Argv[0].

Comment: The recommended way is to use the command line only, and pass `NULL` for the *lpApplicationName* argument. The application name needs to be quoted, if it contains spaces. Use both arguments only, if you need to pass a non-standard command line (one, that doesn't contain the executable image's path name as the first argument) to the process being created.

Comment: @IInspectable,  What do you base your recommendation on?  Read the MSDN page for CreateProcess under "security remarks"  the issue is described then...  "To avoid this problem, do not pass NULL for lpApplicationName. If you do pass NULL for lpApplicationName...".   So Microsoft recommends do not pass NULL, but if you do then use quotation marks.

Comment: The recommendation is based on logical reasoning. Most applications expect the executable image that started the process as the first argument (`argv[0]`). For those cases, passing *lpCommandLine* is sufficient, and prevents generating duplicate, redundant information. Passing both *lpApplicationName* and *lpCommandLine* allows to construct a command line, that doesn't contain the executable image as its first argument. It should be used for those rare cases, where an application expects a (non-standard) command line, that doesn't have the executable image as its first argument.

Comment: If you use `lpApplicationName` then the system won't use the `PATH` environment variable to locate the executable, which might be **not** what you want. So I must second @IInspectable about using `lpCommandLine`, with properly quoted path as the preferred option. You should use `lpApplicationName` only in case the exact executable you're going to launch is known by its absolute path.

Answer (score 3):

I never use lpApplicationName and always quote the application part of lpCommandLine, in your example I would execute `"C:\Path\To\Notepad.exe" "C:\Path\To\File\To\Load.txt"` (Quoting all paths passed to CreateProcess is a good idea) Just using lpApplicationName can cause problems with child processes that access argv[0] which is why I stay away from it.

---

`<rant>`
Using CreateProcess on anything other than yourself can be problematic since NT6+ can at any point decide that the thing you are executing requires admin rights because of application compatibility shims and/or installer detection and then CreateProcess just fails. Unless you need to use the debug or break away from job flags, I would suggest just calling ShellExecute[Ex] to be on the safe side...`</rant>`

Comment: The last point you make about usiung ShellExecute is interesting, that's what we were initially using, but we had to move to createprocess because Adobe Reader needs the current user's enviroment block specified (so it looks in the users documents folder rather than system profile), and I don't think you can do that with ShellExecute. If we use shell execute and Adobe Reader is the default handler, it loads, but just crashes as it denied access to systemprofile folders. Any suggestions? :)

Comment: @Andy: it's a rant. Don't take it seriously. The real problem is executing random strings, e.g. from the registry, without knowing what they point to. If you don't know what you're executing then yes, you may try to start installers. As for starting Adobe Reader, that's a clear case for `ShellExecute`. Don't try to guess what I use as a PDF reader. I'm not using Adobe, partially because it's buggy.

Answer (score 1):

[According to MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682425%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), *lpApplicationName* is optional and can be NULL. In that case, the module name must be the first white space–delimited token in the lpCommandLine string.

If the executable module is a 16-bit application, lpApplicationName should be NULL, and the string pointed to by lpCommandLine should specify the executable module as well as its arguments.